# Setting background color to white when using cmap with a gradient that doesn't contains white

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, gradient

So I have this matrix, which is defined as follows:

```
for row in range (0,squareSize):
            for col in range (0,squareSize):
                if new_matrix[row][col]==1:
                    new_matrix[row][col]=color_matrix[row][col] #gradient given by values in color_matrix 
                if new_matrix[row][col]==2:
                    new_matrix[row][col]=150 #color red
                if new_matrix[row][col]==0:
                    new_matrix[row][col]=100 #color purple
```

SquareSize is 185, the entries which are zero are the points inside the circle, and the entries which are 2 are the ones inside the square but outside the circle.
Both of them are mapped to different colors, and the rest is mapped according to a color gradient given by:

```
cmap = mpl.cm.hsv
```

After plotting it using:

```
plt.matshow(new_matrix, interpolation='nearest',cmap=cmap)
```

This is the output: [image]

However, I want the circle to be white... which is not part of the gradient colors :( How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set those values which you want to appear white to `NaN`. This would prevent them from being drawn at all, such that in those regions the background color is shown. The background is white by default, so they'll appear in white.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x,y=np.meshgrid(np.arange(185),np.arange(185))
data = np.exp(-((x-185//2)**2+(y-185//2)**2)/60.**2)

data[(x-185//2)**2+(y-185//2)**2 > 80**2 ] = np.nan

plt.imshow(data, cmap=plt.cm.hsv)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]